# Unable to highlight the value in select tag using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

********below is the code in html file********

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Count:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem"
                 ng-options="obj.name for obj in listObj">

            </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    ******code in js******


   var listCount = [];
    for(var i=1;i<6;i++){
        var obj = {
            "name":i,
            "value":i
        };
        listCount.push(obj);

    };
    $scope.listObj = listCount;
```

****// response Iam getting name and value in between 1 to 6****

```
scope.selectedItem= {"name":response.name,
                "value":frac.convert(response.value, false).numerator
};
```

Comment: can you specify what the actual problem is?

Comment: By default need to show the $scope.selectdItem in dropdown

Comment: if response is an array of objects then your $scope.selectedItem as is will be undefined. Also notice there is a '$' sign missing in your scope declaration for 'scope.selectedItem'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
for(var i = 0, len = $scope.listObj.length; i < len; i++) {
   if(response.name === $scope.listObj[i].name) {
      $scope.selectedItem = $scope.listObj[i];
      break;
   }
}
```

If you want to select an item, $scope.selectedItem should refer to that item in $scope.listObj array.